# Is a recursive function call with go dangerous?

Tags: go

I'm trying to get familiar with Go, trying out it's keyword `go` for calling subroutines on the fly. I'm wondering if that keyword isn't a bit dangerous to use, cause it might create a dangerous infinity loop which eats all system memory and crashing the host within seconds, if unnoticed.

So let's pretend someone wants to create a recursive function, which is calling itself several times and to increase calculations, it's using the `go` keyword, to increase parallel calculations. Should there some little bug in the code, it would produce likely a dangerously infinite loop.

Below is an example of this dangerously infinity loop.

```
/* WARNING! Running this code will probably crash your system! */

package main

func infinity() {
    LOOP:
    go infinity()
    goto LOOP
}

func main() {
    infinity()
}

/* WARNING! Running this code will probably crash your system! */
```

This code was eating round about 32gb system memory within 7 seconds on my machine, when no more system memory availible, the machine just freezes and it seems there is no chance to unfreeze, other than a hard reset.

So wouldn't you agree that it would be wise to use always a counter variable with an abort criterium when using the `go` keyword?

Comment: what do you mean by "dangerous"? If you write bad code, bad things happen ;-) Also note that in principle, recursion and concurrency (as enabled by the `go` keyword) are different things.

Comment: This code is nonsensical and wrong. But that doesn't mean that "it would be wise to use always a counter variable with an abort criterium when using the "go" keyword?" Span as many goroutines you want and/or need. Nothing about `go` is more dangerous than about `/` (division) or `for`. If you write stupid code stupid code will be executed leading to bad outcome.

Comment: I agree @Volker, but in my opinion, the ability for an unprivileged user to crash nearly any system with the use of this _nonsensical and wrong_ code is a bit overpowered in the hands of a criminal. Do I miss something? Could someone "test" this code on a Windows machine? **(Please make sure you do not lose any data!)**

Comment: It is trivial in any language to thrash your system. Just allocate too much memory. Or span too many threads. Or open too many files. Or fill the disk. Or or or... Your code doesn't do any harm to your computer at all, it just consumes an arbitrary large amount of resources but this is confined to a single process.

Comment: Allocating too much memory gives you the *out of memory error*. Resulting in the crash of the application and not the system (in modern OS). Spanning too many threads are often limited by the OS, to not allow you to span too many threads. Every normal interpreter doesn't allow such infinite loops without at least a warning. Opening too many files or filling the disk does take time and not just 7 seconds and it also doesn't crash the system. In my eyes this is a serious security risk of the language itself. But maybe I'm too inexperienced to be able to judging that.

Comment: What your "dangerous code" does is exactly what you describe as harmless. It just eats up all your memory and your program will be killed by the OOM killer. It will use GOMAXPROCS many threads. That's all. There is _nothing_ dangerous here. A goroutine is "lightweight" but has finit footprint and launching millions of them will exhaust memory like allocating a 4k buffer in a loop. (Btw. "Every normal interpreter doesn't allow such infinite loops without at least a warning" is an exaggeration as most "interpreters" are incapable of solving the halting problem).

Comment: I ran your test program. It didn't crash my system, which continued running OK. It used around 180% of CPU, and use 120+GB of VM the last time I looked at it. The OS  eventually killed it. (macos, but I expect any *nix would do the same.)  I see what your concern is, but it's really no different than an infinite loop in C that malloc's memory, or any recursive function in any language that has no base case. In this respect, C, D, emacs, Haskell, Lisp, Python, Perl, Ruby, Tcl ... are all "dangerous" languages with dangerous features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All loops which do not terminate and allocate resources without freeing these resources are "dangerous" as they will exhaust the available resource (you might call this a "leak").

Infinite recursion is a case of such a loop, even if no goroutines are spaned as maximum stack size will be exhausted .

Such loops (direct or via recursion) are programming errors.

Such loops are not "dangerous", they just exhaust the leaking resource, and, depending on the resource and the underlying OS, this will result in a failure or program termination.

Your code leaks goroutines which consume memory thus your code exhaust the available memory. This is bad but not "dangerous". The underlying problem is not the `go` keyword but memory leakage. Any endless loop allocating memory (and keeping it alive) will result in the same behaviour.

In Go it is easier to leak goroutines than to leak memory. But your conclusion that the go keyword is dangerous and always should be used with a terminating condition is unwarranted.